# Geometry question about bisecting angles

Tags: geometry

This is a question from a past year competition paper.

Let $\triangle ABC$ be a triangle and let $O$ be its circumcentre. Let $D$ and $M$ be points on $BC$ such that
$AD$ is perpendicular to $BC$ and $AM$ bisects the angle at $A$.
Prove that $AM$ bisects the $\angle OAD$.

Could I get some help as to what theorems are helpful for solving this question?
Thank you[image]

Comment: Please add a geogebra diagram with your question it helps a lot.

Comment: @AryanRaina I'm not sure how to attach a geogebra diagram

Comment: Dude download geogebra on playstore if you are on Android else you can search for there website. If you know a bit of elementary constructions you can draw to the scale diagrams of your geometry problems.

Comment: Did you just want a screenshot of the diagram?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Direct angle chasing works. Let the angles of the triangle be $ \alpha, \beta, \gamma$.

What is $\angle BAO$?

> **Hint:** Consider Isosceles triangle $BAO$. What is $ \angle AOB$?

What is $\angle DAC$?

> **Hint:** Consider right triangle $DAC$. What is $\angle ACD$?

Hence, show that $\angle OAM = 90^\circ - \gamma - \frac{\alpha}{2} = \angle MAD$.

Comment: From intuition I see that $$\angle BAO=\angle DAC$$ but I cannot prove that either.

Comment: do you mean like how to rewrite $BAO$ and $DAC$?

Comment: Yes, if it can be proved that, $$\angle BAO=\angle DAC$$, then the proof is done.

Comment: @TamasKantiGarai Can you express $ \angle BAO$ in terms of the angles of the triangle? Can you express $ angle DAC$ in term of the angles of the triangle?

Comment: Yeah, I understand. $\angle DAC=90°-\angle C$ and $\angle BAO=90°-\angle C$.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

First we consider $\triangle BAO$, here,
$$\angle BOA=2.\angle C$$,since $The$ 
 $center$ $angle$ $is$ $twice$ $the$ $circumference$ $angle$ and
$$\begin{align}
\angle BAO=\angle ABO&=\frac {1}{2} (180°-\angle BOA)\\&=\frac {1}{2} (180°-2.\angle C)\\&=90°-\angle C \end{align}$$
Now we consider the $\triangle ACD$, here
$$\angle DAC=90°-\angle C$$
So, $$\begin{align}
\angle BAO=\angle DAC
& \implies \angle BAM+ \angle MAO=\angle MAD +\angle CAM \\& \implies \angle MAO=\angle MAD
\end{align}$$,since $\angle BAM =\angle CAM$ as $AM$ bisects the $\angle A$.